# SQL change condition in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to use a conditional statement in my where clause

```
select * from table where a = b
```

if `b = null or b = ''` it should be `c = d` instead of `a = b`

How do i do this?

Comment: Why do you store ' ' when you mean NULL? Shouldn't even be allowed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use conditional logic:

```
where (b is not null and b <> '' and a = b) or
      ((b is null or b = '') and c = d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CASE WHEN b IS NOT NULL OR b = '' THEN c = d ELSE a=b END
```

Comment: Remove the "AS result", as it causes a syntax error.

Comment: @jarlh removing "As result" will not work. Whole where condition is wrong

Comment: @Sandeep I have tested it after removing AS it's working fine.

Comment: @DipakDendage are you sure? you will get message like Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: @Sandeep Yes 100% just run above query in phpmyadmin. If you have doubt then try to run in mysql I'm sure your doubt will clear.

Comment: @DipakDendage ha ha you are using MySql and me SQL SERVER

Comment: @Sandeep Dude that's why just check logic. At starting I created an alias it's required for query builder.

Thanks .

Comment: @DipakDendage only sql is used in question tag that's why misunderstanding happened. In sql server your query will give syntax error